# Layout - How to rename related lists?

Tags: related-list, custom, page-layout

I did a many-to-many relationship between a custom object (bug) and Case,

I'm now working on layouts and I can't find how to change the name of related lists, or objects, I could use any help !

I surrounded with red the name I'd like to change on the next screenshot,

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the Related List Label by modifying the Related List Label field on the field that references the parent object. In your case, if you go to the object CaseBugJunctionObject, edit the field that references the Case object, you can change the Related List Label. Note that this label must be the same for all layouts that this Related List is shown on. Standard relationships can't generally be changed, but will be automatically adjusted if you use the [Rename Tabs and Labels](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_rename.htm&type=5) feature.

Comment: It's a shame the label has to be the same for all layouts, isn't it ?
Thanks, tho.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the related list name of a standard object on the layout - you can with Salesforce new Dynamic feature from 2021/2022. Navigate to the Lightning Page Record by clicking Edit Page from gear icon - select Dynamic Related List - Single -> and then change the Label name to whatever you want

[image]